# How to avoid reading comments in text file?

Tags: c++, parsing, input, output, readfile

Currently I've successfully write to my file some random numbers between 0 to 10 with this code(below is just some sample code to demonstrate the problem):

```
for (int i = 1; i <= size; i++)
{
    type = rand () % 3;
    switch (type)
    {
    case 0:  afile << rand () % 10;
             break;
    case 1:  afile << rand () % 10;
             afile << "\t\t";
             afile << rand () % 10;
             break;
    case 2:  afile << rand () % 10;
             afile << "\t\t";
             afile << rand () % 10;
             afile << "\t\t";
             afile << rand () % 10;
             /*afile << "8";
             afile << "\t";
             afile << "7";
             afile << "\t";
             afile << "2";*/
    }

    afile << "\t\t" << "// Possible type " << i << endl;
}
```

then my `afile` look like this after executing the code:

```
8       // Possible type 1
1       7       // Possible type 2
4       0       3       // Possible type 3
```

The problem occur when I read the data from this file and output to another file:

```
int type;

while (afile >> type)
{
    if(type == 0) 
    {
        afile >> .........;
        ..........
    } 
        else if(type == 1) {.........}
        else if(type == 2) {.........}
    }       
}
......................................
```

My output file stop reading after the first line since it's also read the comment which is invalid data to process, if I delete the comment then everything is working fine. So how can I overcome this situation? Thank you.

Comment: you need to check if the character\data it is processing is equal to "\".. if this happens then it immediately breaks or gets the next line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've a couple reasonable options:

- read the entire line into a `std::string`, scan for and remove any comment, then create a `std::istringstream` from whatever's left and stream from that to extract the non-comment values
- before reading values, use `>> std::ws` and `afile.peek()` to see if the next character is a `'/'`: if so skip until you reach a newline.

The former is a useful technique to get used to in C++ (helps when you want to report line numbers with data issues), and looks like this:

```
if (std::ifstream in(filename))
{
    std::string line;
    while (getline(in, line))
    {
        std::string::size_type n = line.find("//");
        if (n != std::string::npos)
            line.erase(n);

        std::istringstream iss(line);

        int atype;
        while (iss >> atype)
            ...etc...
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Tony D already provided a reasonable answer as I see, but I thought I'd add a code of my own too, since I already wrote and tested it.

The below is pretty much self-explanatory for anybody speaking C++, it's basically what Tony proposed, but with a twist - getting the data line by line, making use of `std::stringstream`, <s>but then also making use of the binary nature of the data OP uses. The data there is either a valid integer, or a comment. Or in other terms, either a valid integer, or not. So in the code below when a valid conversion of the data from the stream to integer can't be made - the rest of the line is treated as a comment.</s> edit: ...actually, while it was a somewhat valid solution, I modified the code to incorporate a bit saner approach - one that skips a comment (denoted by `#` or `//` to show two ways to do it) but still lets us decide what to do on a malformed value. This does not allow for a `45fubar` to pass as `45` and then bad `fubar`, which was a problem with the previous code, but allows for `45//comment` to be interpreted correctly.

I still think just outright cutting out `\/\/.*?` is a better approach though. The point of this answer though is to be a bit different. ;)

```cpp
#include <ctime>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

void write(std::ostream& output, int lines) {
    for (int i = 0; i < lines; i++) {  // for i lines
        int n = rand() % 10 + 1;       // generate n numbers per line
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {  // loop over line
            output << rand() % 99;     // output a random number
            if (j + 1 < n) {           // if not last?
                output << "\t\t";      // then add tabs
            }
        }
        output << " // " << n << " numbers\n"; // I'm not using std::endl here because it actually *flushes* the stream - flushing every iteration isn't advisable
    }
}

std::vector<std::vector<int>> read(std::istream& input) {
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> v;           // a vector of vectors of ints
    std::string line;               
    while (std::getline(input, line)) {        // getline returns the stream by reference, so this handles EOF
        std::stringstream ss(line);            // create a stringstream out of line
        int n = 0;                          
        std::vector<int> numbers_in_line;
        while (ss) {                           // while the stream is good
            std::string word;
            if (ss >> word) {                  // if there's still data to get
                std::stringstream tester(word);
                tester >> n;
                if (tester && tester.peek() == std::char_traits<char>::eof()) { // conversion went well, no data was left in stream
                    numbers_in_line.push_back(n);   // push it to the vector
                } else {         // conversion didn't go well, or went well but data was left in the stream
                    bool conversion_went_well = tester.good();
                    tester.clear();
                    char c = tester.get();
                    if (c == '#' || (c == '/' && tester.peek() == '/')) { // if it's a comment
                        if (conversion_went_well) {
                            numbers_in_line.push_back(n);                 // push it to the vector
                        }
                        break;                                            // and ignore the rest of the line
                    } else {
                        std::cerr << "Unexpected symbol: '" << tester.str() << "'\n"; // report unexpected data
                        //  so how do we handle a malformed value?
                        //  error out? ignore following values in this line? accept following values in this line?
                        // if you leave it as is now - it will accept following values from this line
                    }

                } 
            }
        }
        v.push_back(numbers_in_line);       
    }

    return v;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::srand(std::time(nullptr));
    write(std::cout, 4);                                    // write random data
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> numbers = read(std::cin); // read the data

    for (std::vector<int> line: numbers) {  // loop over vector via C++11 features
        for (int n: line) {
            std::cerr << n << " ";
        }
        std::cerr << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

An example run:

```
$ ./test.exe < data > data
50 44 92 43 97
26 32 54
30 91
93 4
$ cat data
50      44      92      43      97 // 5 numbers
26      32      54 // 3 numbers
30      91 // 2 numbers
93      4 // 2 numbers


$ ./test.exe < data2 > dump
Unexpected symbol: 'i91'
Unexpected symbol: '4i'
Unexpected symbol: 'lol'
Unexpected symbol: 'numbers'
50 44 92 43 97
26 32 54
30
93 3 2
7337
7337
$ cat data2
50      44      92      43      97 // 5 numbers
26      32      54 # 3 numbers
30      i91 // 2 numbers
93      4i      lol 3 2 numbers
7337//test comment
7337#test comment 2
```

Comment: Nice suggestion Xupicor.  BTW, if the stream's not at `eof()` after parsing the numbers, you could use `ss.clear();` then `ss.get() == '/' && ss.get() == '/'` to ensure there is a comment....

Comment: Thank you for your effort but I'm not familiar with vector at this moment since I'm just a rookie. I'll come back to your solution in the future since it looks quite sophisticated! :)

Comment: @Resolution: `std::vector` is just a standard container from the Standard Template Library (STL). You can just treat it like an array that dynamically allocates memory for itself. Pretty much everything in the code is compliant with standard C++, though some are C++11 specific, like the nice *for* loop. ;)

Comment: @TonyD Your solution of just finding `//` and erasing what's after is pretty much what I'd do - unless a string containing it could be a well-formed data, which it doesn't look like. The whole point of me writing it like that was to exploit the nature of the data, and to be a bit different answer than yours. ;) Still... Check out the edit in a minute.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to do this.

**Skipping the rest of a line after you find a quote (Faster)**

Basically what you would do here, is read the file line by line in a loop. When you hit two characters "//". You'd call "break;" and skip to the next line.'

Some untested dummy code:

```
while(line = file.getLine()){
  loopChars = sizeof(line);
  for(x = 0; x < loopChars; x++) {
    char currentChar = line[x];
    if(x+1 < loopChars){
       char nextChar = line[x+1];
    } else {
       char nextChar = '';
    }

    if(nextChar == "/" && currentChar == "/"){
      // Go to next line 
      break; 
    } else {
      // Do your normal processing here
    }
  }
}
```

**Removing Quotes First (slower)**

Here is a solution for removing quotes (one liners "//" and multi-liners "/**/") from a file. Basically, you would run this against the file you are processing before you start reading it for the number data.

http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/80380/

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main (){
    ifstream infile;
    string filename;
    ofstream outfile;
    char c1, c2;
    bool isInsideComment = false;

    cout << "Please input file name (to remove comments from): ";
    cin >> filename;

    infile.open (filename.c_str());
    if (infile.fail()) {
        cout << "nInvaild file name.n";
        return 1;
    }
    outfile.open(("out_"+filename).c_str());

    infile.get (c1);
    while (!infile.eof()) {
        if ((c1 == '/') && (!isInsideComment)) {
            infile.get (c2);
            if (c2 == '*')
            isInsideComment = true;
            else if ((c1 == '/') && (c2 == '/'))
            isInsideComment = true;
            else {
                outfile.put (c1);
                outfile.put (c2);
            }
        }

        else if ( (c1 == '*') && isInsideComment) {
            infile.get (c2);
            if (c2 == '/')
            isInsideComment = false;
            else if ((c1 == 'n') && isInsideComment)
            isInsideComment = false;
        }
        else if (!isInsideComment)
        outfile.put (c1);
        infile.get (c1);
    }
    infile.close();
    outfile.close();
}
```

Comment: Your use of `!infile.eof()` isn't robust... it's only guaranteed to be set after attempting to read past the end of file, so if `infile.get(c1);` reads a character and there are no further characters in the file, it still won't have set `eof`, and will proceed to `infile.get(c2);` which will fail leaving `c2` unchanged (potentially uninitialised), before trying to compare `c2` with '*' and '/' (potentially undefined behaviour) and likely calling `outfile.put(c2);`.

Comment: Yep, that can lead to bugs in software, when you see `while (!stream.eof())` you should start being very cautious. ;)