# How to skip to next line after the last number found in each line when reading a text file?

Tags: c++, parsing, input, output, readfile

My text file look something like this:

```
1    2   3      test//test
4    5   6    dummy//dummy
```

How can I read this file and only process the numbers present in each line?

Comment: read about the ignore function

Comment: Xupicor's answer to your *very* similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31338380/410767) can be easily adapter to this requirement... have you tried anything?

Comment: @TonyD Actually I've done the task based on your answer , this is quite a redundant question lol :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two ways:

1. By [ignoring the rest of the line](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore).
2. By [reading the complete line](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) into [a string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string), put the string in [an output string stream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream), and read only the leading three numbers from the output string stream.